# Letter 'C' just beside app delegate file in project navigator

Tags: xcode, version-control, project

There is a letter 'C' just beside the app delegate file in the project navigator. Why is that there?  I know the letter 'M' is there to notify me that the file has been modified, but I'm not sure about the letter 'C'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates a Conflict between your local file and the repository.  In other words, you checked out, someone else checked out, they checked in, and now yours is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

it means you have a conflict in your code.. if the conflict is resolved you can mark the file as resolved in the utilities bar when you have your file open